# ActiveMerchant requiring pin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, credit-card, activemerchant

I am using activemerchant in a rails application like this

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::UsaEpayGateway.new(
  :login => "SOMEKEY"
)
```

and I keep getting this error code

```
error_code: \"10117\"\nauth_code: \"000000\"\nstatus: Error\nerror: Transaction authentication required.\n
```

when i look at the error codes (10117) for [usaepay](http://wiki.usaepay.com/developer/errorcodes) I notice that i need to enter in the pin. This I have, but i dont know how to implement. I tried these two below

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::UsaEpayGateway.new(
  :login => "SOMEKEY",
  :password => "MYPIN"
)

ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::UsaEpayGateway.new(
  :login => "SOMEKEY",
  :pin => "MYPIN"
)
```

and I still get the same error
Looking at the USAEPAY Library's initializer I see login but not pin

```
  def initialize(options = {})
    requires!(options, :login)
    @options = options
    super
   end
```

...any ideas how I can sent this pin into [Activemerchant](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant)

**UPDATE**

here is my call to the transaction

```
options = {
  :card_code=>self.card_verification
  :billing_address=>{
    :address1=>self.billing_address,
    :city=>self.city,
    :state=>self.state,
    :zip=>self.zip,
    :country=>"US"
  }
}
response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card, options)
```

i tried to do this

```
options = {
  :card_code=>self.card_verification,
  :pin=>"333333",
  :billing_address=>{
    :address1=>self.billing_address,
    :city=>self.city,
    :state=>self.state,
    :zip=>self.zip,
    :country=>"US"
  }
}
response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card, options)
```

but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to pass the authorization pin into the transaction. Can you paste the code where you call a transaction, please?

For example, calling this method: `capture(money, authorization, options = {})`

**Edit:**

I don't think ActiveMerchant has the pin feature implemented. Here are your options:

1. Use another script. Here are some examples: http://wiki.usaepay.com/developer/ruby
2. Add this to your Gemfile: `gem 'activemerchant', :git => 'git://github.com/kalinchuk/active_merchant.git'` It will install a gem from my github account. I added the pin field to active merchant.

---

You can then call:

```
::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::UsaEpayGateway.new(
    :login => "SOMEKEY",
    :pin => "PIN"
)
```

Comment: pasted in my question...let me know if there is anything else i can give you to help me